# How To Hide Printed Text

Tags: python

How do i make python hide text that was printed earlier in the project? (I'm using repl if that changes anything.) Like imagine my code was. print('Loading')
Name = input('Enter Username')
how would I make the word "Loading" Hide 10 seconds later?

Comment: ```print()``` command is for output and it can't be undone so basically you can't hide with print . I would show you how to do it with sleep if you wait a few minutes

Comment: All I can think of is printing out a whole load of new lines 10 seconds after doing `print('Loading')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python hide already printed text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813667/python-hide-already-printed-text)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the interpreter console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-the-interpreter-console)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the OS module might work. You could use `os.system("cls") to clear EVERYTHING in the terminal. This might not work on repl though.

Try this:

```python
import os
from time import sleep

print("Hello world!")
sleep(1)
os.system("cls") #"clear" For Linux
print("This came AFTER hello world line")
sleep(1)
```

Comment: repl is just Ubuntu, so it would.

Answer (score 0):

so I couldn't write in little time due to something :

```
import time
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()

stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Hello")
stdscr.refresh()

time.sleep(1)

stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "World! (with curses)")
stdscr.refresh()
```

I think it can answer your question.

Comment: amazing! it basically switches out the new text with the old! Thank you i really appreciate it. :)