# I just want to update first print statment in my python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

look at my simple code, i just want when user put correct or wrong answer then above score in print statement update automatic.

```
score = 10
print("="*50 + "[ Your Score: "+ str(score) +" ]" + "="*50)

inputs = raw_input("5 + 5 = ")
if inputs == '10':
    score += 10
    # then i want to update the above print statement
```

> result:

```
=======================[ Your Score: 10 ]=====================
5 + 5 = 10
```

Comment: so... just `print` again? What's the issue?

Comment: `inputs` is a string & you're comparing it with an integer

Comment: i don't want to print new statement because i have more challenges in it. like after addition there is sub, and multiply and many more. according to you i have to print every time after a wrong or right answer

Comment: @rdas sorry for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear terminal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084508/clear-terminal-in-python)

Comment: i have hundred calculations like 5+5  so after every right or wrong answer i want to update score and show it in previous print statement not in new one

Comment: You can't change the already printed output, if that's what you want You'll just have to print again every time the score updates. Or better yet just put an input option like '/score' to print the score when the user wants it?

Comment: @JamesBurgess no it's not

Comment: @UrasGungorPhys so you say i have to print every time a new line

Comment: @aaravsoni yeah, you'd have to create a Graphical User Interface (GUI) to be able to change things on the screen, it doesn't happen on the interpreter

Answer (score 1):

You can't update an already printed output.

You will have to clear your output and reprint with the new score.
Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071230/clear-output-and-rewrite-it-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

you can use While loop.

```
   score=10
   inputs = raw_input("5 + 5 = ")
   while(input==10):
       score+=10
       print("="*50 + "[ Your Score: "+ str(score) +" ]" + "="*50)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def update(score):
    print("="*50 + "[ Your Score: "+ str(score) +" ]" + "="*50)

score = 10
update(score)
inputs=input("5 + 5 = ")
if inputs == '10':
    score += 10
    update(score)
```

---

Just try this.