# Is there any function to clear the console in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm coding a game like a quiz game in "Pycharm", and I want the console to be cleared after each question is asked. In Replit there is a built in function as "clear()" which allows you to clear the console at any point in your code.
From what I know, in python on windows "cls" clears the console but manually and it's not a function that we can use in our codes.
can anyone help me with that?

I've tried:

import os
def clear():
os.system('cls')

and

import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')

yet it doesn't work and only shows a broken emoji.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear/overwrite standard output in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071230/clear-overwrite-standard-output-in-python)

Comment: You can run system commands like "cls" in python using the `os` library, allowing you to clear the screen in this way. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/518007.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-clear-python-shell
i guess that should help.

```
from os import system, name
from time import sleep
def clear():
      _ = system('cls')

print(“Hi Learner!!”)
sleep(5)
clear()
```